# Tautology example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to verify if this logical statement is a tautology?

AB+BCD+AC=NOT(AB+AC)

I have seen all the posibilities but I am not sure that is tautology.
And I have to solve it and to do all the calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by "$AB$" and "$+$"?

Comment: A and B are two variables.A is a invert variable

Comment: "a invert variable": can you explain ???

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not a tautology.

Set $D=0$ and the equation turns to $AB+AC=NOT(AB+AC)$ ?!